# Await subscribe not working

Tags: typescript, async-await

When a button is clicked inside my application. I need to upload certain items to the API before I can carry on with the next step of functionality.

I have tried a lot of things to wait for the code to run but it seem not to work and just move on.

Here is an example of my code:

```
// Gets fired on button click
onSendEmailClick(): void {
    if (this.selectedEmail.Content) {
        let attachments = this.assignEmailContent();
        this.fireAfterCompleted(attachments);
    }
}

// Gets called by button click
assignEmailContent() {
    return this.assignEmailAttachments();
}

// Need attachmentsArray to be fully populated before returning items
async assignEmailAttachments() {
    let attachmentArray: any[] = this.selectedAttachments.map(async (item) => {
        const response = await this.subscribeToContainerItem(item);
        attachmentArray.push(response);
    });
    return attachmentArray;
}

// Calls a API method to get item
async subscribeToContainerItem(item: any) {
  this._azureStorageService.getContainerItemByContainerIdItemName(this._routeIdService.getStorageContainerId(), item.Name).subscribe(async (res: any) => {
        return ({ filename: item.Name, path: res.url });
    }, err => {
        return (err);
    });
}

// API Request
getContainerItemByContainerIdItemName(containerId: string, itemName: string) {
    let httpOptions = this.prepareOptions();
    return this._http.get(environment.API + containerId + '/' + itemName, httpOptions);
}
```

So really the method assignEmailAttachments needs to await the response before moving on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscribeToContainer looks incorrect, here you need to convert asynchronous callback based API (assume it is RxJs Observable) to Promise. Most of such cases can be done via Promise constructor:

```
subscribeToContainerItem(item: any) {
    // immediately return promise instance
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // call inner API and wait for async response
        this._azureStorageService.getContainerItemByContainerIdItemName(this._routeIdService.getStorageContainerId(), item.Name)
            .subscribe(
                // in callback call resolve function to resolve the promise
                res => resolve({ filename: item.Name, path: res.url }), 
                // in case of error reject result promise
                err => reject(err)
            );
    });
}
```

For attachments you need to wait for all attachments to be populated. I made function shorter a bit:

```
assignEmailAttachments() {
    // map each element to async operation which resolves with populated item
    const populatedAttachmentPromises = this.selectedAttachments.map(item => this.subscribeToContainerItem(item));
    // wraps them with promise, which be resolved when all items are populated
    return Promise.all(populatedAttachmentPromises);
}
```

then in `onClick` handler you need wait for promise resolution as well before going further:

```
onSendEmailClick(): void {
    if (this.selectedEmail.Content) {
        this.assignEmailContent()
            .then(attachments => this.fireAfterCompleted(attachments));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks great, do i have to wrap a promise in the `subscribeToContainerItem` method?

Comment: Added some notes on subscribeToContainerItem also